# Find the fill of a child SVG node with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, svg

I have an svg with 5 children > 1 circle and 4 paths. Each has a a different fill color. Is it possible to understand which child has been clicked and return the fill?

Something like...

```
$("#svgname").click( function(){
    alert($(clickedchildname).attr("fill"));
 });
```

Thank you.

UPDATE:

My code is set up like this...

HTML

```
<div class="">
    <img src="img/colorsystem/darkblue.svg" height="170" width="170" id="darkblue">
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#darkblue").children('g').children().click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("fill"));
});
```

SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg>
<g id="darkblueholder">
    <circle id="base" class="st0" cx="85.1" cy="84.3" r="71.4"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `children` method, when the svg is inline:

```
$("#svgname").children().click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("fill"));
});
```

or referenced by `use`:

```
<svg height="170" width="170">
   <use id="svgname" xlink:href="img/colorsystem/darkblue.svg#darkblueholder"></use>
</svg>

$($("#svgname").attr("instanceRoot")).children().click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("fill"));
});
```

You can even specify child type using `.children('path, circle')`.

It is **not** possible to access svg tree loaded using `img`.

Comment: Thank you @pavel I cannot seem to get this running. I updated my post above with my code. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks SO much!

Comment: @andehlu As Pavel stressed, you can *not* interact with the SVG if it's laded using `<img>`. You'll have to inline it. If I remember correctly, the `<use>` method suggested by Pavel only worked in Firefox in the past - not sure whether anything changed there.